# how to switch between nvim config files

Tags: neovim

I have two projects 'Javascript' and 'Python', how I can run different config files for different projects? Maybe exist param for config file? example:

> nvim --configFile .config/nvim/init_py.vim

My goal is to have setup by programming language.

Answer (score 1):

In the nvim manual on linux, it lists that it defaults to .config/nvim IF the environment variable XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set.

I believe you can set on linux the global variable using the command "set XDG_CONFIG_HOME={new config path}"

Answer (score 1):

Building on @guilherme-silva's answer and [this issue](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/5196):

You can try out new config files by setting the environment variables `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` for the config-folder, and `XDG_DATA_HOME` for the "data"-folter (packer, lsp installs etc., normally `~/.local/share/nvim`

```bash
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/nvim-tryout/config
export XDG_DATA_HOME=~/nvim-tryout/data

mkdir -p $XDG_DATA_HOME $XDG_CONFIG_HOME
nvim
```

or instead of polluting your shell env, you can switch them in the same shell command when starting nvim:

```bash
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/nvim-tryout/config XDG_DATA_HOME=~/nvim-tryout/data nvim
```

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption your normal nvim is located at:
~/.config/nvim
~/.local/share/nvim

and the config you want to work on or try out is located at:
~/.config/nvimA
~/.local/share/nvimA

Then you could write a zsh function like so.

```bash
switchnvim() {
    mv ~/.config/nvim ~/.config/nvim_old
    mv ~/.config/nvimA ~/.config/nvim
    mv ~/.config/nvim_old ~/.config/nvimA

    mv ~/.local/share/nvim ~/.local/share/nvim_old
    mv ~/.local/share/nvimA ~/.local/share/nvim
    mv ~/.local/share/nvim_old ~/.local/share/nvimA
}
```

This is what I ended up doing as the environment variable one interfered  with a few other odd configs I setup.

Answer (score 0):

nvim has `-u vimrc` option flag, for using vimrc instead of the default ~/.config/nvim/init.vim